# mvc jquery find a hidden value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc project. And ı want to .on() click function with jquery. razor codes and js codes below,

```
<div class="cart-info">

                  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <tr>

                          <th  class="name">Adres Tanımı</th>
                          <th class="model">Adresim</th>
                          <th class="quantity">Şehir</th>
                          <th class="price">Aktifliği</th>
                          <th class="total">İşlemler</th>
                      </tr>
                      @if (Model.Addresses.Any())
                      {


                          foreach (var item in Model.Addresses)
                          {
                              <tr>

                                  <td    class="name"><a href="#">@item.AddressName</a></td>
                                  <td class="model">@item.AddressLine1 @item.AddressLine2</td>
                                  <td class="quantity">@item.City </td>
                                  @{

                                      var result = item.AddressStatus == true ? "Aktif" : "Pasif";
                                  }
                                  <td class="price">@result</td>
                                  <td class="total"><a href="" class="update-address"><img class="tooltip-test" data-original-title="Değiştir" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/update.png")" alt="Değiştir"><input type="hidden" class="find-me" value="@item.AddressID"/></a>
                                      <a href="" id="delete-address"><img class="tooltip-test" data-original-title="Sil"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/remove.png")" alt="Sil"></a></td>
                              </tr>
                          }
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          <tr><td colspan="5"> Kayıtlı Adres Bulunamadı</td></tr>
                      }

                  </table>

              </div>
```

js work When I clicked .update-address. code below,

```
$('.update-address').on({
click:function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var message = ???????;//
    $.ajax({
        url:'Account/GetAddress',
        type: 'GET',
        data: message,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        //................................

    });

}
```

});

But I cant find .find-me value. How can I find this value with jquery? thanks for reply.

Comment: $(".find-me").val() ?

Comment: I want to find clicked .find-me

Comment: did try to give it name and use selector with it. and are you sure it is the reading the value of hidden field. Try debug it with Developer tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved;

codes below,

```
$('td.total a.update-address').on({
click:function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var message = $(this).find('.find-me').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'Account/GetAddress',
        type: 'GET',
        data: message,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        //................................

    });

}
```

});